# how to analyze numerical and categorical variables at the same time?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, data-analysis, correlation

I'm trying to analyze the data of a **food ordering** application,
the data consist of both numerical and categorical variables, the main variable I'm studying is the **total delivery time** of an order, which represent the time from placing the order to closing it, I want to study what are the variables the affects it the most.

an example of rows in the data is the following:

| order id | branch id | date | time placed | day | period | items id | no. items | total no. items | total delivery time | total time in seconds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 113113 | 31 | 2/2/2021 | 13:32:24 | Tuesday | afternoon | 571 | 4 | 11 | 00:46:19 | 2805 |
| 113113 | 31 | 2/2/2021 | 13:32:24 | Tuesday | afternoon | 573 | 4 | 11 | 00:46:19 | 2805 |

I want to study the effects of all the variables on the total time, even items id and branch id, does a certain item affect time? does the day and period of the day affect it as well?

I used linear regression to get the correlation between total time and the numerical variables, and tried one way anova for some categorical variables, but I didn't like the results, is there a way to analyze all variable together without encoding categorical variables?

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking forward to seeing what other people say about this. Here's my two cents.

ML algos like Regression, love numbers. ML algos like Classification love labels (non-numbers). You can certainly convert labeled data to 'numbered' data. One example is to code ['red','green','blue'] with [1,2,3], would produce weird things like 'red' is lower than 'blue', and if you average a 'red' and a 'blue' you will get a 'green'. Another more subtle example might happen when you code ['low', 'medium', 'high'] with [1,2,3]. In the latter case it might happen to have an ordering which makes sense, however, some subtle inconsistencies might happen when 'medium' in not in the middle of 'low' and 'high'. Now, under the hood, I think classifiers convert labels to numbers, so if you feed in large, medium, and small, it isn't using large, medium, and small to do it's analysis, it's converting those categories to numbers. I think. Maybe someone can confirm this for me.

Thus, I don't think it makes sense to try to measure any kind of relationship between IDs and specific outcomes, like 'totaltime', 'totaldays', etc. If you kick off a project on a Monday or a Friday, does the project end sooner or later than non-Monday-start or non-Friday-start projects? Well, maybe it does. But, is that correlation or causation? You can find correlations between all kinds of things, but these don't necessarily imply causation between these same things.  Let's say you find a strong relationship between multiple projects that start on the second Monday of the month and all of these projects get finished off much faster than all other projects. This seems like pure coincidence, rather than causation. Or, there is some other factor impacting the outcome. Maybe projects that start on the second Monday of the month are typically small upgrades, rather than full-blown new undertakings, so the volume of work is less, and the project is done faster. However, starting the work on the second Monday of the month doesn't CAUSE the project to be finished off faster. Tell me if I am wrong. I'm always open to feedback.

Comment: Yeah I totally agree with you, converting categorical to numbers doesn't make since must of the time, even though days could be seen as ordinal, I don't agree with that, but for a food ordering days and time of the day really affect the orders flow, people are more likely to order at night and at the end of the week, but also event thought morning is least busy hours it is still has the slowest average for orders. What do you think is way I can use to measure all these effects though they are different? I want to give suggestions on how to lower the total time, sorry for the long replay

Comment: Maybe these links will help.

https://github.com/snehanshu17/Predicting-Food-Delivery-Time---Hackathon-by-IMS-Proschool

https://github.com/deepakgupta1/Genpact-Meal-Orders-Forecasting-Challenge/blob/master/xgboost.ipynb

https://github.com/deepakgupta1/Genpact-Meal-Orders-Forecasting-Challenge/blob/master/catboost.ipynb

Comment: Here is one more link for you to learn from. As you can see, the author still converts categorical items to numerical items, using OHE, to do the analysis.

https://github.com/WillKoehrsen/feature-selector/blob/master/Feature%20Selector%20Usage.ipynb

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll definitely check them and tell you what I found best.